# OpenGL issue when 3rd party plug-ins also use OpenGL

Tags: opengl, plugins, concurrency, crash

I'm working on a **program containing an OpenGL view** (using Ogre3D); this program **hosts third-party plug-ins** (namely, VST) which can have their own UI opened. Some plug-ins also use OpenGL for their UI and make **the program crash in the Ogre Render System as soon as this plug-in-specific OpenGL UI is opened** (no crash with other non-opengl plug-ins' UI).

```
Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Thread 0 Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0 GLEngine              gleRunVertexSubmitImmediate + 722
1 GLEngine              gleLLVMArrayFunc + 60
2 GLEngine              gleSetVertexArrayFunc + 116
3 GLEngine              gleDrawArraysOrElements_ExecCore + 1514
4 GLEngine              glDrawElements_Exec + 834
5 libGL.dylib           glDrawElements + 52
6 RenderSystem_GL.dylib Ogre::GLRenderSystem::_Render(...)...
...
22 Ogre Ogre::Root::renderOneFrame() + 30
23 com.mycompany.myapp MyOgreWidget::paint()
...

(apparently a third-party thread from the plug-in)
Thread 10: Dipatch queue: com.apple.opengl.glvmDoWork
0 libSystem.B.dylib          mach_msg_trap + 10
1 libSystem.B.dylib          mach_msg + 68
2 libCoreVMClient.dylib      cvmsServ_BuildModularFunction + 195
3 libCoreVMClient.dylib      CVMSBuildModularFunction + 98
4 libGLProgrammability.dylib glvm_deferred_build_modular(voi*) + 254
5 libSystem.B.dylib          _dispatch_queue_drain + 249
6 libSystem.B.dylib          _dispatch_queue_invoke + 50
7 libSystem.B.dylib          _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 249
8 libSystem.B.dylib          _pthread_wqthread + 390
9 libSystem.B.dylib          start_wqthread + 30
```

I suspected that the OpenGL Context was not properly managed, either in Ogre3D or in the plug-in's UI, but it is not possible to access the plug-ins' render callbacks.

I tested with Ogre3D 1.7.1 and 1.7.3. My UI toolkit is Qt (version 4.6.3 and 4.7.4). Same issues with MacOSX and Windows.

I know other programs with OpenGL views which don't have this issue, even with the exact same plug-ins, I wonder how they handle such situations.

Any idea how to handle that?

Thanks for any help. All the best.

Comment: I could bridge the plug-in into a separate process but that would be painfull.

Answer (score 0):

> Any idea how to handle that?

I'd add a call to `QGLWidget::doneCurrent` right after finishing your own (=Ogre3D's) OpenGL work, and do a `QGLWidget::makeCurrent` before doing your own OpenGL work.

Comment: Well, when using QGLWidget, if I do that I get a crash as soon as I render the the Ogre view; anyway, the doc says about QGLWidget::paintGL "There is no need to call makeCurrent() because this has already been done when this function is called". However the doneCurrent() is apparently not called in glDraw(), which is the paintGL() caller...

Comment: I just reimplemented virtual void glDraw() { QGLWidget::glDraw(); doneCurrent(); } which also crashed at the same moment without a readable stack.

Comment: Anyway Ogre3D normally handles its own OpenGL context correctly.